# PHP Class get Method Always Returns Empty

Tags: php, function, class, oop

This has been driving me nuts... I can't seem to figure out why my  `getJava` function does not work:

```
<?php

class Cup
{

    public $java = null;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->java = "four";
    }

    function getJava() {
        return $this->java;
    }

}

$asset = new Cup;

echo "Item: " . $asset->java . "<br />";
echo "Item: " . $asset->getJava . "<br />";

// Debug
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($asset);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

It outputs:

```
Item: four
Item: 
object(Cup)#1 (1) {
["java"]=>
string(4) "four"
}
```

Comment: You're calling a method: `$asset->getJava()`.... `$asset->getJava` would be valid for directly accessing a public property `getJava` of instance `$asset`

Comment: @user3583258 - Feeling dumb is nature's way of reminding us to recognise the same mistake in future :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you try to access undefined property `getJava` instead of `getJava()` method. Try the following:

```
echo "Item: " . $asset->getJava() . "<br />";
```